# Problem with java socket, won't listen for more than one datagram package

Tags: java, sockets, udp, package, datagram

I'm creating a server(now called Server1) which is communicating with another server i've got(now called Server2).

- Server1 sends a datagrampackage to Server2.
- Server2 is supposed to send two datagram packages back, but i only get one back.
- Server2 is not the problem, and sends two packages.

I use Wireshark to sniff the packages that leaves and comes to Server1.

> Package one(from wireshark):
>   "5955 11994.023974 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.2 UDP Source
>   port: 50000 Destination port: 50004"
>
> Package two(from wireshark): 
>   5958 11994.045830 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.2 ICMP Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)

Server1 runs a Thread which is listening for datagram packages.

Code Server1:

```
     while (m_keepRunning)
    {
        try
        {
         TermMsg receivedMessage = null;
         receivedMessage = receive();   //See this function further down
         if (receivedMessage != null)
            {
                if (receivedMessage.getMsgType().equals(TermMsgType.ACK))
                {
                 System.out.println("This is an ack!");
                }
                else
                {

                 System.out.println("This is a response");
                }
            }
         else
         {
          System.out.println("This is nothing");
         }

        }
```

Receive function:

```
      private TermMsg receive() throws IOException, TermMsgException
{
  byte[] inBuf = new byte[BUF_SIZE_RX];
  DatagramPacket inData = new DatagramPacket(inBuf, BUF_SIZE_RX);

    if(true == firstEncounter)
    {
            StartMessage startReq = getStartMsg(false);
     DatagramPacket p = makeDatagramP(startReq);
     socket.send(p);
     firstEncounter = false;
    }

    socket.receive(inData);
    if (inData.getLength() > 0)
    {
        Msg msg;
        try
        {
            msg = Msg.createFromUdp(inData.getData());
            return msg;
        }
        catch (TermMsgException e1)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
     try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue?
btw... i also use:

```
DatagramSocket socket;
try {
  socket = new DatagramSocket(50004);
}
```

Do i have to use server socket to make it listen for more than one datagram package?

Summary:
- Port unreachable
- Can't receive package number two

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think that you're sending two packets from server2? I don't know wireshark, but it looks to me like you're only sending one UDP packet. The second log message appears to be an ICMP packet, which is a different protocol.

Comment: I thought that ICMP is a message that can tell you if either a udp or tcp packet has not reached its target. But it may look like you are right.

Made a small client that sends packages to Server1, and it responds.
So looks like Server2 does not send two packages at all.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem, as already mentioned in the comments on the question, is that you are assuming that the following two lines are two UDP packets being sent.

```
Package one(from wireshark): "5955 11994.023974 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.2 UDP Source port: 50000 Destination port: 50004"

Package two(from wireshark): 5958 11994.045830 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.2 ICMP Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
```

In actual fact, this is probably an incomplete trace, since this is showing two packages:

```
Package one(from wireshark): "5955 11994.023974 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.2 UDP Source port: 50000 Destination port: 50004"
```

This is a UDP packet, from server2 (192.168.1.3) to server1 (192.168.1.2). It is being sent to port 50004 on server1.

```
Package two(from wireshark): 5958 11994.045830 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.2 ICMP Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
```

This is a control message being sent from server2 to server1 saying that a previous packet could not be delivered because the destination port was not open. This is an answer from a previous packet delivery attempt from server1 to server2, that did not work. This might help to explain why you are not getting all the packets that you expect?

Comment: "This is an answer from a previous packet delivery attempt from server1 to server2"

- This is what i have been thinking all the time, but i can't understand why it can't reach it's destination.

- As i said in another comment, i made a script that sent packages ti Server1, and they reached their target.

Comment: It still does show package two from wireshark, but i have now accomplished to receive both packages.
Thanks for the brainstorming; kdgregory and Paul Wagland :)

Comment: Is there a firewall blocking access to the port?